# jQuery noConflict() not working with multiselect and daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to jQuery,and have a problem,I'm trying to create on one page calendar and multiselect dropdown,but I have problem that they use different js libraries and they conflict with each other. Tried to use noConflict,but it didn't help,or I used it wrong.Scripts themselves work fine.But when I trying to unite them, multiselect stop working.I don`t know what to do.  I will be very grateful for any help.

It`s photo how it works,as you can see multiselect is not working fine.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdHx1.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <!--DatePicker Start-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
        <!--Datepicker end-->


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $j= $.noConflict(true);
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" id="framework_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" id="demo" class="form-control" style="width: 40%"  />
            <label>Select which Framework you have knowledge</label>
            <select id="framework" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control" >
                <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
                <option value="CakePHP">CakePHP</option>
                <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
                <option value="YII">YII</option>
                <option value="Zend">Zend</option>
                <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
                <option value="Phalcon">Phalcon</option>
                <option value="Slim">Slim</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="export_tasks" value="Task Excel Export" class="btn btn-facebook">
        </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
                "ranges": {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                },
                drops: "up",
                autoUpdateInput: false,
                locale: {
                    cancelLabel: 'Clear'

            }
        });

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
        });

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });

    $j(function(){
        $j('#framework').multiselect({
            nonSelectedText: 'Select Framework',
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            buttonWidth:'400px'
        });

        $j('#framework_form').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $j(this).serialize();
            $j.ajax({
                url:"insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:form_data,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $j('#framework option:selected').each(function(){
                        $j(this).prop('selected', false);
                    });
                    $j('#framework').multiselect('refresh');
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This lesson I used to create multiselect jquery list.

http://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/bootstrap-multi-select-dropdown-with-checkboxes-using-jquery-in-php.html

This I used to create daterangepicker
http://www.daterangepicker.com

Comment: You really shouldn’t use more the one jQuery version on you website. This will result in many problems, and unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @t.niese Ahh,ok,thanks